Azure DevOps - No testing results found using VSTest@2 task
I'm working on a .NET 4.5 project and trying to use Azure DevOps pipelines to publish the test results but I keep getting an error:

The report file pattern 'D:\a_temp/**/*.xml' found no matching files.

I'm using VSTest@2:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: '.NET Framework Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    configuration: 'Release'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\${{ parameters.projectName }}\${{ parameters.testDllPattern}}.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    otherConsoleOptions: '\collect:Code Coverage;Format=Cobertura'

I understand this task creates a .coverage file instead of a .xml.
So I looked around and found this dotnet-coverageconverter.
And I tried to implement it:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Install tool: dotnet-coverageconverter"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'update --global dotnet-coverageconverter'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Convert .coverage to .coveragexml'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet-coverageconverter --CoverageFilesFolder "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults" --verbose'

But then I run the report generator script and it doesn't find any .xml files:
- script: reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/*.cobertura.xml;$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/*.coveragexml -targetdir:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/Reports -reporttypes:"HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura;Badges;SonarQube"
  displayName: 'Create coverage report for Azure Pipeline'

My questions are:

What am doing wrong?
Is there any other way of converting this .coverage to .xml?

With .NET Core projects, it's easy with netcli tasks. But with legacy .NET, I'm having trouble.
Thank you in advance.

When using VSTest@2 task, code coverage report is saved in a .coverage file and will be published to the pipeline automatically by default.
According to your yaml file, you have changed the code coverage format to Cobertura by otherConsoleOptions: '\collect:Code Coverage;Format=Cobertura'. In this case, the report is saved in a .cobertura.xml file, which can be seen in the log of VSTest@2 task. To publish this report to the pipeline, you can use PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 task or reportgenerator@5 task.
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\bin\**\*Collector.dll'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    otherConsoleOptions: '/collect:"Code Coverage;Format=Cobertura"'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/*.*.cobertura.xml'

Or
- task: reportgenerator@5
  inputs:
    reports: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/*.*.cobertura.xml'
    targetdir: 'coveragereport'
    publishCodeCoverageResults: true

Result:


Thank you for the response.
I'm still getting the same error though: "The report file pattern 'D:\a_temp/**/..cobertura.xml' found no matching files.".

Hi @Weedosaurus, can you share the completed yaml file of your pipeline? Besides, please check and clarify: 1. Please check the log of VSTest@3 task to see whether the code coverage report was generated successfully. If is was generated, you can see message Attachments:  D:\a\_temp\TestResults\***\VssAdministrator_***.***.cobertura.xml. 2.In which task you see the error "The report file pattern 'D:\a_temp/**/..cobertura.xml' found no matching files."?

Thank you again for the response. After some research I found a solution.
It seems it's not that straightforward to get cobertura with a .net project.
I'll post my findings.

I was seeing the error in the reportgenerator script task. I was not able to find those files because it was not making any cobertura. I suppose it was making a coverage file instead.

After some research I found a way to achieve my goal with coverlet and by disabling auto generate coverage:
stages:
- stage: Build
  variables:
    disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true' -> Disabling autogenerate coverage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildPackage
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: TestAutomation
(..)

Then installing and using a coverlet script:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install --tool-path . coverlet.console
  displayName: Install Coverlet.Console tool

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
        Get-ChildItem **\${{ parameters.projectName }}\**\bin\* -Filter "*.framework.tests.dll" -Recurse |
        Foreach-Object { 
        .\coverlet.exe $_.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($_.FullName) --logger:trx" --format "cobertura"
        $NewName = $_.Name + ".coverage.cobertura.xml"
        Rename-Item coverage.cobertura.xml $NewName

        Write-Host "Generated Coverage Report: $NewName at $(Get-Location)"
        }
  displayName: Generate Coverlet coverage report for test libraries

Then, since coverlet creates the xml file in the default working directory:
- script: reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)\**\*.cobertura.xml;$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/Reports -reporttypes:"HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura;Badges;SonarQube"
  displayName: 'Create coverage report for Azure Pipeline'

The first directory is for a .net core project and the second with System.DefaultWorkingDirectory is for the .Net project I was having troubles with.
To finish it off I also do a Publish:
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\Reports\Cobertura.xml'

I already had this publishing task but it was not reaching since it was failing in the reportgenerator script task.
